# jQuery Select2 issue with shown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am working on a select menu where I use Select-2 plugin to customize it as I would like to. Thereby I have an issue I try to recreate the selected items in the input field. So when you select an item it appear as small grey list item in the input field.

Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sylvanR/041k90py/2/)** which shows the issue I have.

There by this is the javascript code how I render my input field:

```
var selectMenuItems = [
        {id: 'restaurant', value: 'restaurant'},
        {id: 'shopping', value: 'shopping'},
        {id: 'toilet', value: 'toilet'}
    ]

     function formatSelectItem (selectItem) {
        if (!selectItem.id) { return selectItem.value; }
        var $selectItem = $(
        '<img src="img/markers/'+ selectItem.id.toLowerCase() +'.png"/>' +
        '<span class="select-item-text">'+ selectItem.value+"</span>"
        );
        return $selectItem;
    };

    $("[name='select']").select2({
        placeholder: "Selecteer een categorie",
        templateResult: formatSelectItem,
        data: selectMenuItems
    }).on("change", function(e){
        console.log(e);

        $('.select-multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
            var selectedValue = $(selected).val();

            $('.select2-selection__choice').text(selectedValue);
        });
    });
```

The problem is that when I select an item it appears with text inside the input field but if I select multiple all the items will change to that last selected item text. How can I only bind this `.text()` to that specific select item?

In the documentation of the plugin [Select-2 plugin](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) there is an example of called "Templating" where they don't have to appent the text or image to the selected item..

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki that function has nothing to do with this, that will show and appear selected markers in the google maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had to do this with jquery but when I changed the `Array` of selectMenuItems `value` to `text` the plugin does the work for me:

```
 var selectMenuItems = [
   {id: 'restaurant', text: 'restaurant'},
   {id: 'shopping', text: 'shopping'},
   {id: 'toilet', text: 'toilet'}
 ]
```

Just a simple fix where I thought I could set any property there

Comment: Here is a working solution using `text` : http://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/041k90py/10/

Comment: I updated my answer. Is this what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 2):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/041k90py/6/)**.

What you looking for is every time to loop through the selcted values provided by `$(this).val()` and append the value to the `.select2-selection__choice` by index using `.eq()` :

```
$("[name='select']").select2({
  placeholder: "Selecteer een categorie",
  templateResult: formatSelectItem,
  data: selectMenuItems
}).on("change", function(e){
  $.each($(this).val(), function(i, selected) {
    $('.select2-selection__choice').eq(i).prepend(selected+' ');
  });
});
```

**NOTE :** Use `prepend()` instead of `tex()` to preserve the 'X' in the tag.

Hope this helps.

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var selectMenuItems = [
      {id: 'restaurant', value: 'restaurant'},
      {id: 'shopping', value: 'shopping'},
      {id: 'toilet', value: 'toilet'}
    ]

    function formatSelectItem (selectItem) {
      if (!selectItem.id) { return selectItem.value; }
      var $selectItem = $(
        '<img src="img/markers/'+ selectItem.id.toLowerCase() +'.png"/>' +
        '<span class="select-item-text">'+ selectItem.value+"</span>"
      );
      return $selectItem;
    };

    $("[name='select']").select2({
      placeholder: "Selecteer een categorie",
      templateResult: formatSelectItem,
      data: selectMenuItems
    }).on("change", function(e){
      $.each($(this).val(), function(i, selected) {
        $('.select2-selection__choice').eq(i).prepend(selected+' ');
      });
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.flag-text { margin-left: 10px; }

.select2 {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="type" name="select" class="select-multiple" multiple="multiple" data-role="none"></select>
```

**Snippet using pictures :**

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var selectMenuItems = [
      {id: 'restaurant', value: 'restaurant', img: 'https://www.hughesinsurance.co.uk/img/front/map-marker.png'},
      {id: 'shopping', value: 'shopping', img: 'http://king-of-truck.byclickeat.fr/media/cache/square_40/front/bundle/clickeat/img/map-marker.png'},
      {id: 'toilet', value: 'toilet', img: 'http://www.onebabyowner.co.uk/sites/all/themes/onebabyowner/img/icon/map-marker.png'}
    ]

    function formatSelectItem (selectItem) {
      if (!selectItem.id) { return selectItem.value; }
      var $selectItem = $(
        '<img src="'+ selectItem.img +'"/>' +
        '<span class="select-item-text">'+ selectItem.value+"</span>"
      );
      return $selectItem;
    };

    $("[name='select']").select2({
      placeholder: "Selecteer een categorie",
      templateResult: formatSelectItem,
      data: selectMenuItems
    }).on("change", function(e){
      $.each($(this).val(), function(i, selected) {
        $('.select2-selection__choice').eq(i).prepend(selected+' ');
      });
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.flag-text { margin-left: 10px; }

.select2 {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="type" name="select" class="select-multiple" multiple="multiple" data-role="none"></select>
```

Comment: How do include the image inside the option item

Comment: I'm sorry i've missed the other fiddle using the picture, check http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/041k90py/9/.. just by adding an attribute `img` to the object containing the image url, then refer to it in `<img src="'+ selectItem.img +'"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the shortest method:

```
$('.select-multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
   $('.select2-selection__choice').eq(i).text($(this).val());
});
```

If you want to include images in options selected , use `templateSelection` function.You can override the display of the selection by setting the `templateSelection` option to a JavaScript function.

```js
(function($) {
        $(function() {
            var selectMenuItems = [
               {id: 'restaurant', text: 'restaurant', img: 'http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/restaurant-icon-png-7.png'},
               {id: 'shopping', text: 'shopping', img: 'http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Shopping-Free-PNG-Image.png'},
               {id: 'toilet', text: 'toilet', img: 'http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/toilet-icon-png-32.png'}
            ]

            function formatSelectItem (selectItem) {
                if (!selectItem.id) { return selectItem.text; }
                var $selectItem = $(
                    '<img src="'+ selectItem.img +'" width="50px" height="50px"/>' +
                    '<span class="select-item-text">'+ selectItem.text+"</span>"
                );
               return $selectItem;
            };
            function formatState (opt) {
                if (!opt.id) {
                   return opt.text;
                }                               
                var $opt = $(
                  '<span><img src="'+opt.img +'" width="50px" height="50px"/>' + opt.text + '</span>'
                );
                return $opt;
            };
            $("[name='select']").select2({
               placeholder: "Selecteer een categorie",
               templateResult: formatSelectItem,
               templateSelection: formatState,
               data: selectMenuItems
            });
            
        });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.flag-text { margin-left: 10px; }

.select2 {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="type" name="select" class="select-multiple" multiple="multiple" data-role="none"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
        $('.select-multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
            var selectedValue = $(selected).val();

            $('.select2-selection__choice').text(selectedValue);
        });
```

You need to split the `selectedValue` into the values and search each of those to put in the text appropriate for that index of values.

In other words, replace that code as such:

```
     $('.select-multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $('.select2-selection__choice').eq(i).text(selectedValue);
      });
```

Comment: How do I do that? `$(selected).val().split()` and than `$('.select-2....').text(selectedValue[i])`?